# docker-compose: Log to persistent file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I know that docker-compose default logs to a file defined by `docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' my_container`. This file is gone as soon as I kill the container. As I deploy a new version of the image frequently, I loose a lot of log entries.

What I'd like to do is to have my container's log entries stored in a persistent log file, just like regular linux processes use. I can have my deployment script do something like this, but I'm thinking there's a less hack-ish way of doing this:

```
docker-compose logs -t -f >> output-`date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M"`.log'
```

One option would be to configure docker-compsose to log to syslog, but for the time being I'd like to log to a dedicated file.

How have others dealt with the issue of persistent logging?

Comment: killing would not remove those files, only removing the container would. is copying the files somewhere else before removing the containers not an option for you?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess that could work. I'll give it a thought.

Answer (score 1):

So docker has a concept called logging-drivers. https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/#supported-logging-drivers

The default is the file that you mentioned. The ideal way to do this is to pass the `--log-driver <driver-name>` to your run command. Then have another process on the same machine picking these up and pushing to your central logging system.

Most popular of these is `fluentd` or `splunk`, I guess. But you can also choose to write to json or journald.

The docker manual for these are below

- Splunk - https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/splunk/
- Fluentd - https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/fluentd/

Comment: Thanks for the info. I actually ended up logging to syslog for now, as we don't use Splunk and Fluentd and similar.