# symfony docker-compose output log to host

Tags: docker, symfony, logging, docker-compose

I am setting up a Symfony 6/Next js app with `docker-compose` and would like to have the logs from `Monolog` that in Symfony are output to `/var/log/` show on a host file within the app code, so that I can easily review it with VSCode instead of the awkward process of opening a shell.

Note that the logs are correctly output with the container, which is fine.

So I have attempted to create a bind mount, but either it just does not work or it throws an error with `docker-compose up`.

Something like:

```
services:
  php:
    build:
    context: ./api
    target: api_platform_php
    depends_on:
      - database
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
       - php_socket:/var/run/php
       - ./api/var/log:/srv/api/var/log ***HERE***
```

In this specific instance it will error: `setfacl: var/log: Not supported`

I did find a number of related questions on SO, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52852961/docker-compose-log-to-persistent-file), but they either concern overall `docker` logs or are not directly applicable.

Answer (score 3):

Not what you asked, but its common practice to pipe the logs to the container:

Monolog config:
`path: "php://stderr"`

then you can use
`docker-compose logs -f --tail="all" php`

from outside the container

Comment: Hmm... it seems I can get that same info with `docker-compose up` without the `-d` flag. It's messy and unreadable, and ephemeral. Thanks for pointing that practice though.

Comment: thats because it shows logs from all containers. my provided line only shows php container output. (depending on your logging level it can be a lot - or only some info)